# Hiring Manager Response To Thank You email

Tags: interviewing, email

I just received an email in reply to a thank you email to one of the hiring managers. How should I perceive this email?

"It was great meeting you and all the best to you in the future"

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly the same as your thank-you: Ritual polite noise with no information content.

Comment: I think there's information there. The hiring manager's reference to "all the best to you in the future" sounds like the OP isn't getting the job. It might be his/her polite way of dismissing the candidate.

Comment: To me it just sound like "good luck and best wishes, whether you wind up with us or elsewhere." In any case, the only ways to find out are to pester them or to wait. Reading tea leaves is simply not useful, since you should do the same thing either way: continue interviewing until you get a signed contract.

Answer (score 3):

> How should I perceive this email?

You should perceive this as simple politeness and the end of the conversation.

No need to overthink this, or to continue it.